# Firing Projectiles in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to build a weapon in a game using Unity. My bullets spawn but i cant seem to get the force to apply on instantiation to get them to actually fire.

My weapon script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D projectile;
    public float forceMultiplier;
    public Vector2 direction;

    public Transform firePoint;

    private float timeBtwShots;
    public float startTimeBtwShots;

    public void Fire(float force, Vector2 direction)
    {
        Instantiate(projectile, firePoint.position, transform.rotation);  
        projectile.AddForce(direction * force);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (timeBtwShots <= 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            {
                Fire(forceMultiplier, direction);
                timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the force to the spawned object and not the prefab.
Your code should be something like this:

```
    public void Fire(float force, Vector2 direction)
    {
        Rigidbody2D proj = Instantiate(projectile, firePoint.position, transform.rotation);  
        proj.AddForce(direction * force);
    }
```

Comment: brilliant that worked! thanks. one more question: it seems the force thats being applied to the bullet is affected by my characters movespeed. is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Are you sure that is the case? Sounds like you might be colliding with the bullet itself and pushing it forward because of collision applied force, which could lead to unexpected behaviors.

Comment: they shouldnt be interacting. ive set them to ignore collisions between each other. Also i cant seem to fire left :/